# Passing updated state as props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm relatively new to React and wondering if you could take a look at this problem if possible. I'm making an ajax call to an API on a click event and storing the results in the `'SearchButtons'` component's state.

The state is then passed into the child component via the props. However the props in the child component (`SearchForm`) equals the previous state on the parent component and is not updated when the user clicks one of the buttons.

I'm wondering if there is a way around this, maybe updating the component before the props are sent to the child component?

```
import React from 'react';
import SearchForm from './SearchForm'

class SearchButtons extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: {}
    }
  }

  update(event){
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://example/api/' + event.target.value,
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({ data: data })
      }.bind(this)
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button type="button" value="people" onClick={this.update.bind(this)} className="btn btn-primary">People</button>
        <button type="button" value="car" onClick={this.update.bind(this)} className="btn btn-primary">Car</button>
        <button type="button" value="planet" onClick={this.update.bind(this)} className="btn btn-primary">Planet</button>
        <SearchForm data={this.state.data} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default SearchButtons
```

Please see example of the `SearchForm` component below

```
import React from 'react';

class SearchForm extends React.Component {

  componentWillReceiveProps(){
    console.log(this.props.data);
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <form className="form-inline">
        <div className="form-group">
          <label className="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail3"></label>
          <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Enter text..." />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-default">Search</button>
      </form>
    )
  }
}

export default SearchForm
```

Comment: What does `SearchForm` look like?

Comment: Hi Josh, I've just added the code for the SearchForm above. Thanks.

Comment: Is the correct data being returned from the ajax call?

Comment: FYI, unrelated to the problem at hand, but you shouldn't use `for` in your label, you should use `htmlFor`: https://facebook.github.io/react/html-jsx.html

Comment: Hi Azium, Yes, when I log this.state.data in the render function after the correct data is returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`componentWillReceiveProps` receives the *next* props as the first argument, so by logging `this.state.props` you are seeing the *current* props, not the ones that are being received.

Try to log the next ones like this:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    console.log(nextProps.data);
}
```

Of course, you can also check what the new props are *after* they have been updated by calling the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method instead of (or alongside, if you want to monitor both steps) `componentWillReceiveProps`:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    console.log(this.props.data);
}
```

Take a look a the [lifecycle methods](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#lifecycle-methods) if you want to know more!

Comment: Of course I inadvertently click `submit` and my internet dies. Fixed.

Comment: Hi Juandemarco, thank you, that has worked. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

It appears as though you're doing things correctly, and if you render some data from the props in the JSX you'll see the data update as you expect.

componentWillRecieveProps as a lifecycle method is very semantic in what it means, the component WILL receive props but hasn't yet. If you log this.props you'll see the old props. Log the next Props to see the update

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  console.log('new props: ', nextProps);
}
```

This is a very good article that very concisely breaks down each stage of the component life cycle and shows you how each method works:

http://busypeoples.github.io/post/react-component-lifecycle/